# Rails 5: Как переопределить миграцию в Геме

Tags: ruby-on-rails, миграция

Вопрос простой:
Как переопределить или отключить миграцию внутри гема.

Гем: [Payola](https://github.com/payolapayments/payola)

Миграция: [20150930164135_add_tax_percent_to_payola_subscriptions.rb](https://github.com/payolapayments/payola/blob/master/db/migrate/20150930164135_add_tax_percent_to_payola_subscriptions.rb)

Данное поле уже существует. Удалять нельзя, так как в нем нужные данные.

Comment: Форкнуть гем, поменять в своей версии всё, что вам надо, и пользовать ее. Периодически обновлять форк. Ну или переименовать поле в своем приложении

Comment: @Василиса Да Вы правы. Но хотелось бы найти решение на уровне миграций. Временно (видимо навсегда) я переиминоваю конфликтное поле `tax_percent` на время выполнения миграций из гема. В любом случае спасибо.

Comment: Есть хитрый обходной манёвр -- сделать миграцию, которая добавит фиктивную запись о миграции из гема в таблицу с применёнными миграциями, чтобы её реальный запуск был пропущен; а собственные изменения применить самостоятельно. Но это опасно, т. к. если перед применением миграции заранее составляется список, этот механизм при применении всех миграций сразу даст сбой. Но в контролируемой среде, где можно добавить эту запись и затем добавить гем в разных выпусках, это сработает.